# Is there a reason why Ruby's prepend behaves differently when used with modules versus classes?

Tags: ruby, prepend

While monkey-patching a module from a Rails engine, we found that if you prepend a module B to another module A, the prepended module B won't be added to the ancestors of classes that have already included module A prior to the `prepend`. To illustrate:

```
module A
  def a
    puts 'a'
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

module C
  def a
    puts 'c'
  end
  A.prepend self
end

class D
  include A
end

B.new.a # prints: a
D.new.a # prints: c

B.ancestors #=> [B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
D.ancestors #=> [D, C, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Both classes `B` & `D` include `A`, but only `D` takes the new behavior as it's the one defined after we call `prepend`.

In contrast, we learned that class inheritance does not exhibit this behavior:

```
class A
  def a
    puts 'a'
  end
end

class B < A
end

module C
  def a
    puts 'c'
  end

  A.prepend self
end

class D < A
end

B.new.a # prints: c
D.new.a # prints: c

B.ancestors #=> [B, C, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
D.ancestors #=> [D, C, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

This time, both classes `B` & `D` have taken the new behavior, even if `B` was defined before we called `prepend`.

Is there a reason why `prepend` behaves differently when used with modules versus classes? I'm assuming this is by design, but it does present a gotcha when using `prepend` with modules.

Comment: `include` shows the same behavior (apart from the different ancestors order)

Comment: that's a good spot.  it has potential issues for memory usage, if the `include` is essentially bringing in and storing the contents, at the time of creation, in that class, but inheritance might share the same object

Comment: `Module#include` seems to be spec'd that way: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c9325cb8cf38233e3e9ff7e521d56bc427e5c758/spec/ruby/core/module/include_spec.rb#L35 , https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c9325cb8cf38233e3e9ff7e521d56bc427e5c758/spec/ruby/core/module/include_spec.rb#L113. Still trying to track down why/where.

Comment: @engineersmnky interesting! I was under the impression that multiple `include` calls have no additional effect.

Comment: @Stefan So I am not 100% sure on this (because I am not very familiar with C), but assuming rubinius's implementation is close, it appears when you include a module it alters the including object's ancestral stack in a loop (of mod and mod's mods). So once this loop is complete the object's stack is complete. Thus further changes to mods ancestral chain do not reflect in objects that have already included it.

Comment: Essentially each object's ancestry is specific to that object, so `include A` does not reference `A`'s object ancestry. It only references `A` and then traverses `A`'s ancestry including each Object in that chain in ascending order (with avoidance for duplication and inconsistent ordering with previous inclusions)

Comment: Hi @Stefan, @Jad, and @engineersmnky! Thank you very much for looking into my question. I posted the question for two reasons: to make a record of this interesting behavior which other Ruby programmers might also encounter, and to satisfy my curiosity :) That being said, looking at your comments, it seems there is no obvious reason as to why `prepend` and `include` behaves like this. It could simply be "performance reasons" :) I'd like to ask how you'd like to resolve this question? Leave it unanswered? Delete it? Rephrase it so that it's answerable? I'd appreciate to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Found something: [Ruby Bug #9573 – descendants of a module don't gain its future ancestors, but descendants of a class, do](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9573)

Comment: Thank you @Stefan for the bug report! I've confirmed that while the behavior is still present in Ruby 2.7.2, it's no longer present in Ruby 3.0.0. I'll submit an answer to this question.

Comment: Again, thank you @Stefan, Jad, and engineersmnky for thoroughly investigating this issue! I appreciate if you can review the answer I posted. Also, if you think this post will benefit from being converted to a Community Wiki, please let me know and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9573 shows a similar behavior concerning classes and modules. The bug report was posted on 2014 and was only closed 2020. Based on that report, I've manually confirmed that

- This behavior still appears in ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux], but
- This behavior **no longer appears in ruby 3.0.0p0** (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-linux]